# Some issues were found when trying to render this preview - Android Studio Dolphin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-dolphin

Today, I upgraded my Android Studio from Chipmunk to Dolphin, and most of my Composable Previews have stopped working and are giving the error `Some issues were found when trying to render this preview`.

On clicking the **Show Exception** button in the issues panel, I found the following error.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process null. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.`

Most of my composables use Firebase Analytics for event logging purposes and hence `FirebaseAnalytics` is one of the parameters in almost all the composable functions. Until Android Studio Chipmunk, I was able to show the preview for all the composables by following the below approach.

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
private fun DemoPreview() {
    MyAppTheme {
        Demo(firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics, onClick = {})
    }
}
```

But the above method no longer works for Android Studio Dolphin.

Is there any other way to pass the `FirebaseAnalytics` object that makes the Composable Preview work again?

Comment: In my case `Sync Project with Gradle files` helps to show the preview.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Android Studio Chipmunk, if you're seeing **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: view_tree_saved_state_registry_owner** or **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.savedstate.R$id** in the issues panel, make sure to include a debugImplementation dependency to **androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate** in your module.

If you're seeing **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:** view_tree_lifecycle_owner in the issues panel, make sure to include a debugImplementation dependency to **androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime** in your module.

If you're seeing **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class** **androidx.customview.poolingcontainer.PoolingContainer** or **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/customview/poolingcontainer/PoolingContainerListener** in the issues panel, make sure to include a debugImplementation dependency to **androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer** in your module.

Answer (score 1):

When you have parameters to your composable I recommend to totally separate actual functionality and UI:

```
@Composable
private fun DemoContent(analyticsCallback: (input: String) -> Unit, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    // Your UI - call analyticsCallback when needed
}

@Composable
fun DemoScreen(firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    DenoContent(
        analyticsCallback = { input ->
            // Process input with firebase
        },
        onClick
    )
}

@Preview
@Composable
private fun DemoPreview() {
    MyAppTheme {
        DemoContent(
            analyticsCallback = { input ->
                // Log the input
            },
            onClick = { }
        )
    }
}
```

The `input` is just a placeholder - change it to whatever you need to use firebase.

Comment: can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73789740/11560810)