# How to handle permission denied in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose-accompanist

Hey guys I want to handle denied permission in jetpack compose. I found `PermissionsRequired` method in which helpful in my case till now. I got a problem which I explain in detail later. First I'll explain what I did inside this function.

```
class BluetoothRequestActivity : BaseActivity() {

    val permissions = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        listOf(
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        )
    } else {
        listOf(
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        )
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AbcTheme {
                AppBarScaffold() {
                    val multiplePermissionsState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(permissions = permissions)
                    PermissionsRequired(
                        multiplePermissionsState = multiplePermissionsState,
                        permissionsNotGrantedContent = {
                            setupBluetoothRequest(multiplePermissionsState)
                        },
                        permissionsNotAvailableContent = {
                            setupBluetoothRequest(openPermissionSetting = true)
                        }
                    ) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun setupBluetoothRequest(
        multiplePermissionsState: MultiplePermissionsState? = null,
        openPermissionSetting: Boolean = false
    ) {
        BluetoothRequest(
            multiplePermissionsState = multiplePermissionsState,
            openPermissionSetting = openPermissionSetting,
            onCancelClick = {
                finish()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

When first time user open the activity `permissionsNotGrantedContent` will open it shows the **Button** to ask the permission. Now when user denied the permission and click **not ask again** options, I changed the view through `permissionsNotAvailableContent` will tigger and Button functionality change to open System setting. I did this without any problem.

**MAIN PROBLEM**

All things happen then I closed my activity and Reopen the activity. My `PermissionsRequired` always trigger `permissionsNotGrantedContent` this function which is wrong. Right now according to flow user permanently disable the dialog so why this is trigger I want to handle this function `setupBluetoothRequest(openPermissionSetting = true)`. Any idea how can I fix this problem? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have 4 scenario when first user land on screen I want to show `Text - Abc wants permission` and `Button`. When user click on Button it asked runtime permission. It asked 2 options **Allow** and **Denied**. When user **Denied** 2 times I want to show in `Text- you denied please manual open setting and give permission`. If user **Allow** then I want to show `Text - Permission granted` on screen. I did all these 3 scenario without any problem. When user **Denied** the permission 2 times it shows `Text- you denied please manual open setting and give permission` but when user close the screen and reopen screen I am getting `Text - Abc wants permission` and `Button` on screen which I don't want. So how can I solve this problem.

```
setContent {
            AbcTheme {
                AppBarScaffold() {
                    val multiplePermissionsState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(permissions = permissions)
                    when {
                        multiplePermissionsState.shouldShowRationale -> {
                            setupBluetoothRequest(multiplePermissionsState)
                        }
                        multiplePermissionsState.permissionRequested -> {
                            setupBluetoothRequest(openPermissionSetting = true)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE 2**

after updating from `0.23.1` to `0.25.1` I don't see the options of `permissionRequested` anymore.

```
when {
        multiplePermissionsState.allPermissionsGranted -> {
            Text(text = "Permission Granted", color = Color.White)
        }
        multiplePermissionsState.shouldShowRationale ->{
            Text(text = "shouldShowRationale", color = Color.White)
        }
    }
```

So how can I deal now?

Comment: Hi yo. Do you call `permissionsNotAvailableContent` if `multiplePermissionsState.shouldShowRationale` is `true`? I suggest following their sample code: https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/permissions/RequestMultiplePermissionsSample.kt

Comment: I believe `PermissionsRequired` has being removed in latest accompanist versions, update it and follow [documentation sample](https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/)

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel the example is just for grant and denied logic.

Comment: @PhilDukhov I updated my code. But it still the same issue. Can you please guide me on.

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel can you please have a look on updated section in question.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The field permissionRequested  was deleted. The new way that you can check if the permissions were requested is creating a flag initially set to false, and set true when rememberMultiplePermissionsState callback is called.

Try something like this:

```
var permissionRequested by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val permissionsState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(permissions) {
    permissionRequested = true
}
// Use permissionRequested
```

permissionRequested will be set to true when the permission dialog is closed

Comment: You shouldn't do this, since you don't know how many times this was called, or reseted by the system.